# Some issues regarding TIdUDPClient and TIdUDPserver

Tags: delphi, udp, indy

I have a code which sends audio stream from server to client using TIdTCPClient and TIdTCPServer, it works fine, but it is not efficient when using a lot of clients so I decided to use TIdUDPClient and TIdUDPServer instead but have got some problems which I don't understand (I use the latest indy snapshot).
Server part of code:

```
.......
//AudioCallback - is a callback function for a 3rd party lib that prepares audio stream, it is called several times per second
...
var fStream:TFileStream;
...    
procedure AudioCallback(buffer: LPSTR; len: UINT); cdecl;
var
  IdUDPClient: TIdUDPClient;
  IdBytes: TIdBytes;
begin
//len is always 1024
  IdBytes := RawToBytes(buffer^, len);//works bad
{  for cb := 0 to High(IdBytes) do
    IdBytes[cb] := cb mod 256;}//works fine
{  for cb := 0 to High(IdBytes) do
    IdBytes[cb] := Random(255);}//works bad
{  for cb := 0 to High(IdBytes) do
    IdBytes[cb] := cb mod 2;}//works fine
  fStream.Write(IdBytes[0], length(IdBytes));//for testing purposes
  IdUDPClient := TIdUDPClient.Create;
  with IdUDPClient do
    try
      Host := '127.0.0.1';
      Port := 32563;
      try
        Connect;
        if Connected then
          SendBuffer(IdBytes);
        Disconnect;
      except
      end;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

Client part is simple:

```
....
var fStream:TFileStream;
....
procedure TClient.IdUDPReadEvent(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
  fStream.Write(AData[0],length(AData));
end;
....
```

The issues that I don't understand:

1. I tried to use non-local IdUDPClient but the second call of
   methods SendBuffer(IdBytes) or Connect always raises an idException
   "Invalid argument", though the IdUDPClient properties stayed the
   same
2. The packets sent from the server side and received on the
   client differ. I tested it many times. The first received packet is
   always the same. The second and the following others are the same
   only if you manually fill the packet in some regular way like
   IdBytes[cb] := cb mod 256. If you leave it with original data or fill it       with random data - you    receive not what you sent.

Comment: You don't need to use `TIdUDPClient.Connect()` in this situation (`Connect()` does have meaning to UDP, it is just not meaningful in this particular example). Just call `SendBuffer()` by itself, it will send the data to the specified `Host` just fine. Also, while creating and destroying the `TIdUDPClient` object on every callback will "work", it is wasted overhead. I would recommend creating the `TIdUDPClient` object one time before audio starts flowing, and just reuse the same object in each callback event (just don't share it across threads unless you synchronize access to it).

Comment: @Remy Thanks for the tip. Looks like the callback function is called from different threads (I don't know how to test it) and I need to create TIdUDPClient in every call. Could you also help me to find why different values in the sending buffer affect the packet reception? The received data is similar to the sending packet but differs. I thought that's not possible and spent two days trying to find why the received audio file doesn't sound good.

Comment: If you can't reuse a single `TIdUDPClient` object, then so be it. Still get rid of the `Connect()` call, though.  And it is not possible for the server to receive something different than what the client sends, unless the packets are being modified on the network mid-flight. However, the sent packets could be received out of order, so you do need to account for that possibility.  Put an incrementing sequence number in each sent packet, and then have the server buffer and re-order received packets as needed.

Comment: @Remy You were totally right! the packets are received in arbitrary order. I have made synthetic data filling the first packet with zeroes, second with ones etc. And this is what I get on the receivers side: 1 0 2 4 3 6 5 8 7 9. 
Does it make sense to use UDP instead of TCP in this case?

Comment: The problem solved, I increased the buffer size, the callback function now is called once per second, all packets are received in correct order. Thanks!